# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'coordi' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Below is a python function that detects an object and returns its bounding box coordinates:

```
def back_project_dilation(hist1,hist2,hsv,min_area,max_area,min_aspect,max_aspect,min_rect,max_rect):

 Ratio=hist1/hist2
 
 #calculating the M_blue
 #spliting the target channels
 h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

 #backprojecting the R_red hist
 B = Ratio[h.ravel(),s.ravel()]
 B = np.minimum(B,1)
 B = B.reshape(hsv_1.shape[:2])
 B[B >0 ]+=1
 B = np.minimum(B,1) 
 Open=cv2.morphologyEx(B,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
 dilation = cv2.dilate(Open,kernel,iterations = 2)
 #dilation_special=dilation_special.astype(np.uint8)
 dilation*= 255
 dilation=dilation.astype(np.uint8)
 
 contours =cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cntss = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
 if len(cntss) > 0:
   

  # print('ture')
   for cr in cntss:
                 
                 area=cv2.contourArea(cr)
                 
                 (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(cr)
                 
                 aspect=w/float(h)
                                                        
                 if area>=min_area and area<=max_area and aspect>=min_aspect and aspect<=max_aspect:
                     center, (width,height),_=cv2.minAreaRect(cr)
                     rect=area/float((width*height))
                    
                     if rect>=min_rect and rect<=max_rect:
                           
                           
                           
                          
                        coordi = cv2.boundingRect(cr)
 return coordi
```

The detection method used inside the function is called "Histogram_back_projection"

The function is is called a in a while loop four times as the function is being used to detect small cars in two videos simultaneously

```
while True: 
  
ret1,frame1=cap1.read()
ret2,frame2=cap2.read()
cv2.imwrite('image22.jpg',frame1)
if ret1 and ret2 !=True:
    print('cannot open Videos, please cheack your source')
    break
else:
 hsv_1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 hsv_hist_1 = cv2.calcHist([hsv_1.copy()],[0,1],None,[180,256],[0,180,0,256])
 
 hsv_2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 hsv_hist_2 = cv2.calcHist([hsv_2.copy()],[0,1],None,[180,256],[0,180,0,256])
 

 B_red_coord=back_project_dilation(hist_red,hsv_hist_1,hsv_1,619,1090,1.2432432432432432,3.0588235294117645,0.7296458280876743,1)

 B_red_2_coord = back_project_dilation(hist_red,hsv_hist_2,hsv_2,619,1090,1.2432432432432432,3.0588235294117645,0.7296458280876743,1)
 

 B_blue_coord  = back_project_dilation(hist_blue,hsv_hist_1,hsv_1,522,903,0.875,2.68,0.76504332843943325,1.000000410476877)
 B_blue_2_coord  = back_project_dilation(hist_blue,hsv_hist_2,hsv_2,522,903,0.875,2.68,0.76504332843943325,1.000000410476877)
```

So as a result i should obtain 4 outputs as the function is called 4 times (these are Centroids coordinates of two cars in two videos)

When i run the code, the following error occurs:

```
<module>
B_red_2_coord = back_project_dilation(hist_red,hsv_hist_2,hsv_2,619,1090,1.2432432432432432,3.0588235294117645,0.7296458280876743,1)

back_project_dilation
return coordi

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'coordi' referenced before assignment
```

I looked the problem up in stack overflow and found similar one, however i didn't know how to project the suggested solution on my problem

So, I would be grateful for some Help and thanks in Advance

Khaled Jbaili

Comment: what do you expect `coordi` to be? i assume you actually want the results of the funciton `back_project_dilation` which you store into `B_red_2_coord` but that final blob of code is kinda nonsensical.

Comment: @Macattack. coordi is coordinates of bounding box of a related car. the function suppose to return a different result each time it is being called. In my case its assinged to four variables and thus four different coordinates

Comment: You have `B_red_2_coord = back_project_dilation(...)`, `back_project_dilation` and `return coordi` lines of code. What are you expecting `coordi` to be? It hasn't been assigned to be anything. What are you expecting to be returned here?

Comment: @Macattack i'm very sorry. I copied and old mistake. I updated the code. I think you know now to which value coordi is assigned to. My bad

Comment: it just means you're not binding `coordi` to anything. (i.e., you never reach that branch of logic). you can set `coordi = None` at the top of your func to avoid the error

Comment: @acushner while technically correct, somehow I doubt the desired result is for this to return `None` but yes, `coordi` isn't set to anything. We'd just get the next question, "Why am I getting back `None`".

Comment: @Macattack when seeting coordi to None and run the code it returns the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @macattack agreed, and thanks! i was hoping the main takeaway would be "you never reach that branch of logic", i.e., your code is wrong.

Comment: again, @k.jballi, you never reach the branch of code you're expecting to reach. your logic is flawed. your algo is not working. you need to fix the logic.

Comment: @acushner. I believe the logic is fine as the algo ran well before i packed the script in the method back_project_dilation.

Comment: @acushner. I solved the problem by setting coordi as global in the function. Now it works fine. However thnaks. I'll post my aswer

Comment: glad you got it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by setting the variable "coordi" to global